# python : scrapy using proxy IP

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy

I want to use proxy IP for web scraping using scrapy. In order to use a proxy I set the environment variable `http_proxy` as mentioned in the documentation.

`$ export http_proxy=http://proxy:port`

To test whether the change of IP worked, I created a new spider with the name test :

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test"
    domain_name = "whatismyip.com"
    start_urls = ["http://whatismyip.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        print response.body
        open('check_ip.html', 'wb').write(response.body)
```

but if I run this spider the `check_ip.html` do not show the IP as specified in the environment variable rather it shows the original IP as it was before crawling.

What is the problem ? is there any alternative way that I can check whether I am using a proxy IP or not? or is there any other way to use a proxy IP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit settings.py in your current project and make sure you have HttpProxyMiddleware enabled:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = { 
 #you need this line in order to scrap through a proxy/proxy list
'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
}
```

Comment: is there any way to check whether i am scraping through my proxy IP or not ?

Comment: Your approach with your spider example should work, just make sure that http_proxy variable on your system is set and that you have HttpProxyMiddleware enabled...another simple way would be to run your spider against your own web server, simple read your web server log files after that. That is the first thing coming into my mind right now.

Comment: For scrapy 1.2.1, it's scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware

Comment: @Vipul maybe check your environment variables like `env | grep -i proxy`, from [here](https://www.shellhacks.com/linux-proxy-server-settings-set-proxy-command-line/)